# My Vue porperties are not reactive in html

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-props

I have a function that I updates the Vue properties as you interact with the UI, Now My properties are being update and when I console log the result they indeed update but they don't update on the UI part that is the Vue template HTML part

this is a Vue  class component  and I have UpdateUserCryptoBal function that updates the coinBallance and coinType properties

```js
export default class Withdraw extends mixins(Global, Authenticated) {
  walletAssets = JSON.parse(this.$store.getters.userWalletAssets);
  coinBallance = this.walletAssets[0].bal;
  coinType = this.walletAssets[0].symbol;
  coinsAmount: number;
  walletAddress: string;
  transactionFee = 0.0;

   UpdateUserCryptoBal(ballance: any, coinType: any) {
    this.coinBallance = ballance;
    this.coinType = coinType;
    console.log(this.coinType, this.coinBallance);
  }
}
```

This is how I render this property on the template html part

```
<div class="flex px-4 py-4 space-x-4 justify-between overflow-x-scroll scrollbar-hide">
                <div v-for="assets in walletAssets" :key="assets.id">
                    <div @click="UpdateUserCryptoBal(assets.bal, assets.symbol)" class="row__asset shadow-sm rounded-xl text-lg cursor-pointer">
                        {{ assets.symbol }}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p class="mt-5 text-md font-light text-grey-400">{{ coinBallance }} {{ coinType }} Coins Available</p>
```

is there something I am missing in Vue on how to make properties reactive in html?

Comment: are you using vue2 or vue3? if vue3 do you use options api or composable api?

Comment: I am using vu2 with typescript class components

Comment: did you define your properties as `data`?

Comment: when you use typescript  class components you don't do that I guess